# opencv Changing pixel format (YUYV to MJPG) when capturing from webcam?

Tags: c++, linux, opencv

I need to set my webcam to MJPG using the `CV_CAP_PROP_FOURCC`  property to increase the FPS.  If I try to set the parameter to MJPG I get an error of

```
HIGHGUI ERROR: V4L: Property <unknown property string>(6) not supported by device
```

cam1x.cpp

```
#include "opencv2/opencv.hpp"
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <sstream>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <unistd.h>



using namespace cv;
using namespace std;

int main(int, char**)
{
    VideoCapture cap(7); // open the default camera


    //*********trying to set it here****************
    cap.set(CV_CAP_PROP_FOURCC, CV_FOURCC('M','J','P','G') );


    cap.set(CV_CAP_PROP_FRAME_WIDTH,320);
    cap.set(CV_CAP_PROP_FRAME_HEIGHT,280);
    //cap.set(CV_CAP_PROP_CONTRAST, 0.5);
    //cap.set(CV_CAP_PROP_BRIGHTNESS, 0.5);
    if(!cap.isOpened() )  // check if we succeeded
        return -1;
    //double contrast = cap.get(CV_CAP_PROP_CONTRAST);
    //double brightness = cap.get(CV_CAP_PROP_BRIGHTNESS);
    //cout << "Contrast = " << contrast << "BRIghtness" << brightness << endl;


    //Mat edges;
    namedWindow("cam1",1);



    int x = 0;
    while(true)
    {
        x++;
        Mat frame;
        if( !cap.grab())
        {
            cout << "Can not grab images." << endl;
            return -1;
        }
        if(cap.retrieve(frame,3) ){
            imshow("cam1", frame);


        }
        //cap >> frame; // get a new frame from camera
        //cap1 >> frame1;

        //imshow("edges1", frame1);
            //sleep(2);
            if(waitKey(30) >= 0) break;
        }



  // the camera will be deinitialized automatically in VideoCapture destructor
    return 0;
}
```

to show that my camera supports mjpg

```
v4l2-ctl -d /dev/video7 --list-formats
ioctl: VIDIOC_ENUM_FMT
    Index       : 0
    Type        : Video Capture
    Pixel Format: 'UYVY'
    Name        : UYVY 4:2:2

    Index       : 1
    Type        : Video Capture
    Pixel Format: 'MJPG' (compressed)
    Name        : Motion-JPEG
```

How do I fix this problem so that I can set the capture to MJPG without error???

Note that there is a similar question to mines on the opencv forum that is UNANSWERED.

http://answers.opencv.org/question/41899/changing-pixel-format-yuyv-to-mjpg-when-capturing-from-webcam/

Comment: The analogous code in python is working for me, but [I can't set h264/x264](https://answers.opencv.org/question/214284/capture-camera-video-using-h264/) instead of  MJPG. So, I think our problems should have similar solution. If you found anything about it, please, share.

Comment: Have you tried building from source with the flags `WITH_V4L=ON` and `WITH_LIBV4L=ON`?